# nginx install wordpress on /blog under my domain address

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu, wordpress

I have a domain `example.com`, it serves my website using nginx webserver that points to a nodejs docker container 3000 port using `proxy pass` option under `/` location.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    index index.php index.html;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access_example.com.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error_example.com.log;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

now I want to add a wordpress website under `/blog` so I added these configuration under server block.

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }

    location /blog {
        root /var/www;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

Why I cannot access to fresh installed wordpress under `/var/www/blog/`
if I run `curl http://example.com/blog/license.txt` on my terminal, it's OK and I can see the content of `license.txt` file under `/var/www/blog/` but `index.php` not loaded nether `index.html` that I added for test.

I think the problem is with `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` line but I didn't find anything helpful. any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As you are probably aware, Wordpress uses a front controller architecture - i.e. the entry point for running any PHP script is $WORDPRESS_ROOT/index.php. You need to tell nginx to route the requests accordingly:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
```

Note that requests for most static content would be handled by one of the first 2 values. There's no 404 handler as Wordpress needs to handle the scenario itself.

> but index.php not loaded

hmmm, not a very meaningful description of what happened - i.e. did you explicitly as for ..../index.php or just .../ ? What response did you get? What was in your logs?

There's quite a lot of config needed for PHP (and for most fcgi handlers) which is usually included elsewhere in your config. On Ubuntu I would have expected that this is already in place if installed from repo, but testing this out would be advisable. I'd also suggest addressing this BEFORE making the front-controller modification above as this will complicate matters somewhat. Use a simple "hello world" PHP script.

Comment: I changed `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` to `try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;` and now I can see 200 status code if I open `http://example.com/blog/index.html` but `index.php` not works returns 404, it seems like php not properly compiled.

Comment: if i run just the URL nginx log:
`- [24/Jan/2024:14:11:51 +0330] "GET /blog/ HTTP/1.1" 404 118 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0"`

Comment: if i run URL with index.php at the end
`- [24/Jan/2024:14:11:36 +0330] "GET /blog/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 118 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0"`

` - [24/Jan/2024:14:11:36 +0330] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 5037 "http://example.com/blog/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0"`